# get and set method of redis not working in node app

Tags: node.js, redis

Redis is connected properly but after that, it does not show the output of the code.
also Redis client set name as key properly but after that, it doesn't show any error of replay as output, the same thing happen with get method.

```
const express = require('express');
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient();
client.connect();
client.on("connect", (err)=>{
    if(err) throw err; 
    else console.log("Redis Connected!");
});
const app = express();
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    let name = req.query['name'];
    client.set("name", name, (err, replay)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        else console.log(replay); //ok
    });
    client.get("name", (err, name)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        else {
            console.log(`name: ${name}`); 
            res.send(`hello ${name}`);
        }
    });
});

app.listen('3000',()=>{
    console.log("server at 3000.!");
});
```

output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2C2V.jpg

Comment: I think you are using the legacy methods, if you add legacyMode:true to the createClient() does this fix it?

Answer (score 0):

create a client.js file. inside client.js

```
const { createClient } = require('redis');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: './.env' });

const client = createClient({
    socket: {
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        port: parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT),
    },
    password: process.env.REDIS_PW,
});

client.on('error', (err) => console.log(err));
client.connect();

module.exports = client;
```

you can get REDIS_HOST, PORT, PW in redis cloud console.
make sure to store these keys into .env file
now do these:

```
const express = require('express');
const client = require('./client');
const app = express();
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    let name = req.query['name'];
    client.SET("name", name);
    client.get("name", (err, name)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        else {
            console.log(`name: ${name}`); 
            res.send(`hello ${name}`);
        }
    });
});

app.listen('3000',()=>{
    console.log("server at 3000.!");
});
```